# Batch script assist

Tags: batch-processing, remote-access

I have an application running in windows RDP server.
Im looking for ways to execute a script that will automatically restart the services once the application stop.

Regards,
Kelvin

Hello,
I'm new to batch scripting. any guidance will be appreciated.

Regards,
Kelvin